# $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2) (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor))}{\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)}=0$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I want to take the following limit using an $\varepsilon-\delta$ approach:

> $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2)\cdot (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\cdot(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor))}{\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)}$, where $f$ is a strictly decreasing function that has, for every $x \in \mathbb R$, $f(x) \gt 0$.

I believe the limit is $0$ (just wanted to make sure no invalid steps were taken), and the proof proceeds as follows:

---

We want to show that for an arbitrary $\varepsilon \gt 0$, we can find an $M \in \mathbb R$ such that for any $x \gt M$, we have $\left| \frac{f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2)\cdot (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\cdot(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor))}{\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)}\right| \lt \varepsilon$

It is straightforward to show that $0 \leq x-\lfloor x \rfloor \lt 1 \quad (*_1)$, which entails that  $0 \lt 1 - (x-\lfloor x \rfloor) \leq 1\quad (*_2)$. Given that $f(x) \gt 0$ for any $x$, we can conclude that if $x \geq 1$, then

$$\left| \frac{f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2)\cdot (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\cdot(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor))}{\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)}\right|=\frac{f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2)\cdot (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\cdot(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor))}{\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)}$$

Next, by $(*_1)$, we know that $x \lt 1+ \lfloor x \rfloor$. This, combined with the fact that $f$ is a strictly decreasing function, implies that:

$$f(x) \gt f(\lfloor x \rfloor+1) \gt f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2)$$.

By $(*_1)$ and $(*_2)$, we can further conclude that:

$$2f(x) \gt f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2)\cdot (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\cdot(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor))$$

Because $x \geq 1$, we must then have:

$$\frac{f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2)\cdot (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\cdot(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor))}{\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)} \lt \frac{2f(x)}{\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)}=\frac{2}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$

Finally, if in addition to $x \geq 1$ we further stipulate that $\lfloor x \rfloor \gt \frac{2}{\varepsilon}$, then we have that:

$$\left| \frac{f(\lfloor x \rfloor+2)\cdot (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\cdot(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor))}{\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)}\right | \lt\frac{2}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lt \varepsilon$$

To show that such an $x$ exists, we note that the natural numbers are unbounded which means there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $n \gt \frac{2}{\varepsilon}$. If $x \gt n$, then, by definition of the $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ function, we must have that $\lfloor x \rfloor \geq n$, which implies that $x \geq \lfloor x \rfloor \geq n \gt \frac{2}{\varepsilon}$.

Let $M=n$, and we are done.